# Which HTML tag is the proper one to use for Java applets (APPLET, EMBED, OBJECT)?

Tags: java, html, applet

My understanding is that APPLET is deprecated and OBJECT is the preferred tag to use for Java applets.  Is this correct?  A lot of Java applet examples, both on the web and in books, still seem to use the APPLET tag.

Are there any browser compatibility issues that OBJECT suffers from (compared to APPLET)?

Also, can you provide an example of proper OBJECT tag usage for Java applets?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985754

Answer (score 3):

Here is your [best bet](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/versions.html). And here are the [examples](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html) for all tags.